# How can enable swipe image in slide by touch (or mouse) in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can enable touch slide in bootstrap?

for example: [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/tabbed-slider-carousel)

and this is js script:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```

how can do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Did that work? What went wrong? Did you get any errors? You need to include this information in your questions. Please read this guide to make sure your questions are as answer-able as possible: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tutorial](http://lazcreative.com/blog/how-to/how-to-adding-swipe-support-to-bootstraps-carousel/)

You will have to get [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/). Once jQuery Mobile has been downloaded (or created; you can just choose to have touch events to be enabled to decrease file size, [here](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/)).

Here is some code you can use to swipe the carousel:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {
    $("#myCarousel").carousel('prev');
  });
  $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {
    $("#myCarousel").carousel('next');
  });
});
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...But do you think I must use a heavy js lib only for a swipe pic? is there a lighter lib like photoswipe.com/ but I want do it with native bootstrap plugin...

Comment: I believe the jQuery Mobile library is pretty light, *after you select the parts you require*.

Comment: thanks. I got your mean now. size is only 8 kb, it's ok.